Astro With ReactJS
Okay so basically, Im currently making a Web Application with Astro, React and NodeJS.
Im trying to make a dynamic/auto-updated component that will update every few seconds, but right now im having a little problem with even firing the "componentDidMount()" event on a React Component.
This is my React Component Code:
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './css/PieChart.css';
import {db} from "../utils/db.js";

class PieChart extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            percentage: 0
        }
        this.circleRef = React.createRef(); // Create a ref
    }

    render() {
        console.log("Render", this.state.percentage);
        return (
            <div className="circle rounded-full flex" id="piechart" ref={this.circleRef}>
                <p className="z-10">
                    {this.state.percentage}%
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        console.log("ComponentDidMount")
        try {
            let allDoors = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                db.query("SELECT * FROM _doors", function (err, res, fields) {
                    if (err) reject(err)
                    resolve(res)
                })
            })

            let openDoors = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                db.query("SELECT * FROM _doors WHERE occupied = 1", function (err, res, fields) {
                    if (err) reject(err)
                    resolve(res)
                })
            })

            let percentage = openDoors.length / allDoors.length * 100;
            this.setState({percentage: percentage});
            console.log(percentage)
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error in componentDidMount:", error);
        }
    }
}

export default PieChart;

This is astros config (astro.config.mjs)
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';
import tailwind from "@astrojs/tailwind";
import node from "@astrojs/node";
import auth from "auth-astro";
import react from "@astrojs/react";

export default defineConfig({
  integrations: [tailwind(), auth({
    providers: []
  }), react()],
  output: 'hybrid',
  outDir: './docs',
  build: {
    assets: 'astro'
  },
  adapter: node({
    mode: "standalone"
  }),
});

This is the DB file which is making a request to my database.
import mysql from 'mysql'

const sql = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "host",
    user: "user",
    password: "password"
})

let db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "host",
    user: "user",
    password: "password",
    database: "database"
});

sql.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Error connecting to the database with sql:', err);
        throw err;
    }
    console.log("Connected with sql!");

    let sqlQuery = [
        "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS autolock",
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS _doors (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(255), floor VARCHAR(255), adminGroupId INT, password VARCHAR(255), rfid VARCHAR(255), status BOOL)",
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS _users (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(255), adminGroupId INT, jsId VARCHAR(255))",
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS _groups (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(255))"
    ]

    sql.query(sqlQuery[0], sqlError)
})

db.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Error connecting to the database with db:', err);
        throw err;
    }
    console.log("Connected with db!");

    let sqlQuery = [
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS _doors (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(255), floor VARCHAR(255), adminGroupId INT, password VARCHAR(255), rfid VARCHAR(255), status BOOL)",
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS _users (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(255), adminGroupId INT, jsId VARCHAR(255))",
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS _groups (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(255))"
    ]

    db.query(sqlQuery[0], sqlError)
    db.query(sqlQuery[1], sqlError)
    db.query(sqlQuery[2], sqlError)
})

function sqlError(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Error executing query:', err);
        throw err;
    }
    console.log(result)
}

export { sql, db }

In my Index.astro im calling it by just importing it like this.
---
import Layout from "../layouts/Layout.astro";
import DoorTable from "../components/DoorTable.astro";
import PieChartReact from "../components/PieChart.jsx";
import PieChart from "../components/PieChart.astro";
import React from 'react';
---

<Layout title="Welcome to AutoLock.">
    <main>
        <PieChartReact client:load/>
        <DoorTable />
    </main>
</Layout>

<style is:global>
    :root {
        --c: #39463A;
    }
    main {
        margin: 40px;
        width: calc(100% - 80px);
        max-width: calc(100% - 2rem);
        color: white;
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 1.6;
    }
    
    
</style>


The expected result should be the component's state at least being modified. (It should be percentage = 100, based on database results, but its not updating)
